# jQuery recursive function error

Tags: jquery, recursive-query

I am trying to make the following recursive function work but keep receiving an error (following code):

```
var checkStatus = function(jobID) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/admin/process/check-encode-status.php',
            data: {jobID: jobID},
            success: function(data) {
                if (data == 'processing') {
                checkStatus(jobID).delay(2000);
                } else {
                    $("#videoOutput").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
     };
```

The error I am receiving is: `checkStatus(jobID) is undefined`

Everything seems to be working as it should, Firebug is just throwing this warning. The function is repeating itself, posting the jobID and receiving "processing" from the PHP script.

I had a similar script that I was using that used `setTimeout()` to be recursive but I could not figure out how to pass the jobID along with calling the function (errors).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `.delay()` and you'll get rid of the error. You should use `setTimeout` instead.

```
var checkStatus = function (jobID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/admin/process/check-encode-status.php',
        data: {
            jobID: jobID
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 'processing') {
                setTimeout(function() { // <-- send an anonymous function
                    checkStatus(jobID); // <--    that calls checkStatus
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                $("#videoOutput").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

This is because `checkStatus()` doesn't return anything explicitly, so you're trying to call `.delay()` on `undefined`.

Comment: Works great, thanks! Kind of dumb of me to use `.delay()` for that, of course that wouldn't work. Thanks again for the help